# WPF image not showing while foreach statement

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm facing a very strange issue on WPF application. Let me explain clearly what I've done.

I've Datagrid with selecteditems as check box so user select and click on Load button then the record will load to the database server. During this time I kept spinning image while data loading to the database server. since I've lots of records.

By default I've kept image to hidden while data loading property change to visible. Whne it comes foreach statement image never shows or if it is visibility by default image shows but never spins... Any ideas or help on this what i'm doing wrong..?

Xaml code...

```
<Button Content="Load" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1042,83,0,0"
    Name="btnSaveData" Visibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"
    Cursor="Hand" Click="btnSaveData_Click" Foreground="Green" 
    Background="#FFB0D3D3" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14"/>
<Image Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1012,83,0,0" Name="imgSpin5"
    Stretch="None" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Visibility="Hidden"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24"
    Source="/LoadDataSource;component/Images/Spin5.png">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="TransRotate" Angle="0"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
    <Image.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard TargetProperty="Angle">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TransRotate"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" By="360" 
                        Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False" 
                        RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```

C# code..

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Load Selected items?",
   "Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Information);
if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    imgSpin5.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    foreach (CType ctp in dgAttributes.ItemsSource)
    {
        if (ctp.IsSelected)
            imgSpin5.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to do the work on a background thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try wrapping the visibility update in a `Dispatcher.Invoke` call to force it to the top of the UI thread and run your `foreach` on a background worker thread:

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Load Selected items?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        imgSpin5.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.DoWork((s,e)=>{
            foreach (CType ctp in dgAttributes.ItemsSource)
            {
                if (ctp.IsSelected == true)
                {
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        imgSpin5.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
```

Comment: imgSpin5 is a UI element and cannot be modified from a background thread. Guess u didn't see it, can you updated your answer.

Comment: Done, the foreach can now iterate on the background thread and marshal the visibility update to the UI thread when it needs to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... But there are compile errors in the code..Am I missing any namespaces?

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        imgSpin.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    });   Cannot convert lamba expression to system.Deleagte because it is not a delegate Type

Comment: See my update above, use Dispatcher.Invoke, not Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Comment: I've created static ExtensionHelpers and called the static method.it works for 100 loaded data.. but it doesn't work for too much of data. I've to look for that..anyhow thanks for your help mate

Answer (score 0):

if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                {

```
                BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

                backgroundWorker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
                {
                    foreach (CType ctp in dgAttributes.ItemsSource)
                    {
                        if (ctp.IsSelected == true)
                        {

                            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                            {
                                imgSpin.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                            });

                        }

                    }

                };
                backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

                MessageBoxResult results = MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Loaded..!", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.OK);

                imgSpin.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
```